# Como eu faço para remover os caracteres das posições pares em uma string?

Tags: python-3.x

Tenho uma string e quero remover dela apenas os caracteres em posições pares

Comment: Bem vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português! Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a que melhor por causa disto. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/101).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar um *truquezinho* de lista:

```
>>> a = "01234567"
>>> a[::2]
'0246'
>>> a[1::2]
'1357'
```

Coloquei as 2 opções porque não sei se você considera a primeira posição como ímpar ou como par (já que é `a[0]`)